# How i can scrape or retrieve twitter replies?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I tried multiple ways to scrape the replies of tweets 
I tried selenium, it did not work with replies it only get the tweet itself 
Tried tweepy to get the replies but I don't know how to do it correctly ! 
Can anyone help me !?

Answer (score -2):

Check if [Twitter's REST API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs) suits your needs, along with python's [http client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html).

Comment: This should belongs to a comment